# plasma desktop configuration file for dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, configuration, plasma

I don't understand how the `plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` (in `~/.config/`) deals with dual monitors.

Mine seems to only have the options for one of my two monitors.

Is there also some documentation somewhere for further reference?

Comment: That file is not intended for manual editing and is poorly documented. You could ask on the KDE forums - https://forum.kde.org/ . What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I was on a _Quriosity Quest_ to understand how my configuration got all borken, but I only have so much time to spend on it, so if it's neither configurable by hand nor documented, I'll just scrap it, revert to defaults and call it a day. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know there is little to no documentation outside the source code. KDE forums are your best bet as someone there may know.

Comment: Ok, well I'll ask there, and if I elucidate the mystery, I'll come back and answer my question.